# UpdateViews android

Tags: java, android

The task:
Create an updateViews method that sets the text of the status to game.toString().

Problem: 
I am having a problem trying to figure out what this means I tried:

```
private void updateViews(){
    CharSequence d = status.getText();
    game.toString() = d;
}
```

I think I am reading, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the instance of `TextView`, you need to update, simply use `setText` method:

```
private void updateViews(){
    status.setText(game.toString());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
private void updateViews(){
    String d = status.getText();
    game.setText(d);
}
```